# Oozie workflow to move file from local to hdfs

Tags: oozie

I have written an oozie workflow to copy a file from local to hdfs. It does not show any error after running the job, but it does not put the file to hdfs

Here are my codes

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/crazyoozie
focusNodeLogin=cloudera
shellScriptPath= /home/cloudera/Desktop/script.sh
```

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="WorkFlowForSshAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="sshAction"/>
<action name="sshAction">
    <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
    <host>${focusNodeLogin}</host>
    <command>${shellScriptPath}</command>
        <capture-output/>
    </ssh>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<kill name="killAction">
    <message>"Killed job due to error"</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>`
```

script.sh

```
hadoop fs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/oozieinput /oozieresults-sshAction
status=$?
if [ $status = 0 ]; then
    echo "STATUS=SUCCESS"
else
    echo "STATUS=FAIL"
fi
```

The `script.sh` is there in the local FS. The output directory oozieresults-sshAction is there on hdfs.
Could you please help me on this

Comment: Just to confirm, script.sh is in the same server where ooize server is running?

Comment: Yes the script is in the same server where oozie is running.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I see that you are using a ssh action and using a shell script which is conflicting. For executing a shell script you need to create a shell action which will be like this :

    <workflow-app name="WorkFlowForShellAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3">
        <start to='shell' />
        <action name='shell'>
            <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <configuration>
                    <property>
                      <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                      <value>${queueName}</value>
                    </property>
                </configuration>
                <exec>${shellScriptPath}</exec>  
                <file>${shellScriptPath}#${shellscript}</file>                                                  
            </shell>
            <ok to="end" />
            <error to="fail" />
        </action>
        <kill name="fail">
            <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <end name='end' />
    </workflow-app>
===============================================================
JOB.PROPERTIES
===============================================================

nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/crazyoozie
focusNodeLogin=cloudera
shellScriptPath= /path/to/hdfs/script.sh
shellscript= script.sh


In the shellScriptPath give the hdfs path where you place the script
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am running this workflow on a pseudo distributed mode, so this problem should not be there right?

Comment: Sorry Harshi for my ignorance in my first answer. Actually you are using a ssh action to run a shell script. You should use a shell action for the same. I have edited my answer. Please try it. And if you want to run a ssh action then you need to directly write the hadoop command there. There is no need of a script in ssh action. You can go either way.

Comment: Thanks again! But I did not get the value in the <file>. Where will we be storing the path of the file on the local file system and the destination directory? If we are configuring it in job.properties, where will we be calling it in workflow.xml?  Should the script.sh reside in hdfs?
Also how will the job.properties be for this. I am trying to learn oozie, so could you please help me again

Comment: Is there any library that has to be associated with?

Comment: The shell script should be in hdfs and you should use the hdfs path of the script in the job.properties. Add two more properties in the job.properties. Please check my answer above I have updated the job.properties and the workflow.xml. Please use it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi... If I give the direct path of the shell script (in hdfs), the job runs and the logs say that it is successful. Though it shows successful in the logs, I dont see that the file is copied to hdfs from local. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: The job copies the file sometimes to hdfs, then when I delete the file and re run the job, it doesn't copy it again.